# Error when enabling Administration Language for Core Toolbar

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n, toolbar

I downloaded and enabled the `admin_language` module, and in one of its configuration settings, I enabled `Use administration language for the core toolbar`, after which it threw out this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _menu_build_tree()
>   (line 1377 of /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc).

The line 1377 is:

```
$tree_cid = 'links:' . $menu_name . ':tree-data:' . $GLOBALS['language']->language . ':' . hash('sha256', serialize($parameters));
```

I've done this before in another project and it didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `$GLOBALS['language']` wasn't accessible, hence the error. I checked the permissions again and it appears I needed to enable `Select administration language` and `Use all enabled languages`, and then the error went away.